# XPath Namespace issues

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xmpp

When connecting to an XMPP server I get one of these two responses:

```
<stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">
    <mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
       <mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism>
       <mechanism>DIGEST MD5</mechanism>
    </mechanisms>
    <auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth" />
    <register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register" />
</stream:features>
```

OR

```
<stream:features>
    <mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
        <mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism>
        <mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism>
        <mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism>
        <mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism>
    </mechanisms>
    <compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress">
        <method>zlib</method>
    </compression>
    <auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth" />
    <register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register" />
</stream:features>
```

When trying to parse the second one with my code, I get this error:

```
namespace error : Namespace prefix stream on features is not defined
<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism
                ^
```

Here is my code:

```py
mechanisms = []

xmlParsed = libxml2.parseDoc(xmlResponse)

xpathContext = xmlParsed.xpathNewContext()
xpathContext.xpathRegisterNs('urn','http://etherx.jabber.org/streams')
xpathContext.xpathRegisterNs('sasl', 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl')
nodes = xpathContext.xpathEval("//urn:stream/features/sasl:mechanisms/sasl:mechanism/text()|//urn:features/sasl:mechanisms/sasl:mechanism/text()")
for node in nodes:
    mechanisms.append(str(node))
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I right it? Please don't say, use the XMPP libraries or such, I'm not trying to write an entire XMPP client. I just want enough code to register as a user first.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't write your own XMPP library from scratch.  There are already many available from a list on [xmpp.org](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).  In particular, for Python, try [SleekXMPP](http://sleekxmpp.com/).

For example, using parseDoc isn't going to work; you'll need to parse XML incrementally.  The missing prefix definition for "stream" in "stream:features" is a symptom of this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is reported for the `<stream:features>` tag saying that the prefix `stream` is not defined.

`<stream:features>` indicates that the `features` tag is under a namespace represented by prefix `stream` and in your xml fragment there is no such namespace declared.

Comment: The comment about "|" is quite incorrect. The "|" operator means "union" (of two node-sets). It is used perfectly correctly in this example expression. Downvoting the response because of this.